# If a Mount Everest-sized mountain had Earth's sea level atmospheric pressure at the top, what would the atmospheric pressure be at sea level?

Tags: hard-science, atmosphere

I'm designing a world with earthlike gravity where the human colonists are intended to live on top of a gigantic shield volcano as tall as Mount Everest.  What would the pressure be at the bottom?  **Would it be too dense for humans to breathe?**

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close, but I am going to downvote.  A reasonable estimate is found with a 10-second google search.  Current pressure on Everest: 4.89 psi.  Sea level: 14.69 psi.  Basic algebra: 4.89/14.69 = 14.69/X.  X = 44.13 psi.  P.S. your title question is very different from your body text question (how uninhabitable...), which is too broad.

Comment: It would probably be habitable. Big pressure changes are terrible for the human body, but over time it would be 100% plausible for them to slowly migrate down the mountain and adapt to the higher pressure. Usually the problem occurs if you change pressure too fast. Also as JBH mentioned, which question are you asking? the one in the Title or the one in the Body. Please bold it.

Comment: What does 1 Bar at the top mean?

Comment: David Johnson, I've edited your questio so that it is (hopefully) not too broad and answerable. If that doesn't work for you, please edit it again to fit your requirements and fit in with the site's requirements.

Comment: 1 Bar=1 Atmosphere (pressure) approximately.

Comment: @JBH I'm pretty sure atmospheric pressure doesn't follow a linear curve.

Comment: @0something0, oh, it doesn't.  Gas is obviously compressible and so the pressure will be greater than 44psi - but not that much.

Comment: Also 'earth like' gravity is not strong enough to hold that much atmosphere, and then we'll have to consider the stronger gravity effects on beings.

Comment: Deepak Chaudhary, do you know what the atmospheric pressure of Venus is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of basic research.

Comment: The pressure at the bottom would be reasonable. But I'm wondering about the temperature. If the top is warm enough for liquid water, the bottom would be too hot for humans.

Comment: @JBH I disagree. A basic research can tell you what pressure there is at the Everest peak and at sea level, but it doesn't answer the question. Sure, you can interpolate and, in this case, you wouldn't be far off but the thing is I don't know that much about Earth science or gas dynamics and I could be completely wrong in my calculus. That's why I'd ask here. In other words, are we requiring users to already have the knowledge to answer their own questions before they are allowed to ask? What's the point of this site then?

Comment: @Rekesoft, the downvote button rollover begins, "This question does not show any research effort...."  the purpose of this (and all other Stack Exchange sites) is not to be your personal research assistant.  Curiously, your accepted answer varies from my rapid estimation by only 6% and my comment was posted before you edited your question.  We don't require users to have the knowledge to answer their own questions, but we do expect them to demonstrate that they've made an effort to figure it out first.

Comment: @JBH I'm not the one asking the question, I just think the "research effort" requisite being applied a tad too harshly - or worse, arbitriarily. If a question looks too basic for someone who happens to know much about it then it may be marked as lacking researching effort while a trivial question on a less known field will pass. I've thought about opening a discussion in meta about this, but I'm unsure if it's going to get us somewhere.

Comment: @DavidJohnston Currently your question's title and body are asking two different questions. This may be the source of some of your downvotes. I might recommend editing one or the other to reflect whichever of the two questions you most want to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [online calculators](https://www.mide.com/pages/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator) for that.

However, if you assume the same density and radius of Earth, then you can simply increase the pressure by a fixed factor. The factor must be so that pressure at 8800 m (currently about 31% of normal) becomes 1 bar. Which means that it is 1/0.31 = 3.22. Multiply the pressure at sea level by that factor and you get the new sea level pressure - 3.22 bar.

As for survivability, [you have that](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10895/maximum-survivable-atmospheric-pressure) - barely. At 3.21 bar you're skirting nitrogen narcosis ([symptoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_narcosis):  Mild impairment of performance of unpracticed tasks, Mildly impaired reasoning, Mild euphoria possible)

However, you can start with a lower pressure at height (perhaps two thirds of normal), which is easily survivable - you have that in La Paz, Bolivia - and gets you about 2 atmospheres at sea level, also survivable with next to no symptoms.

Answer (score 8):

This [website](https://www.mide.com/pages/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator) has an atmospheric pressure calculator. Since we are assuming that everything about the planet is the same except for the modified atmosphere, plugging in -8000 meters for altitude gives me 2.39 bars of pressure.

But is it survivable?

[image: http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/images/spacesuits/suitAtmo.jpg]

This chart from [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/lifesupport.php) tells me *maybe*. At 2.39 bars or 34.66 pounds per square inch (what the chart uses), we skirt the edge of oxygen toxicity and nitrogen narcosis.

Comment: @Brythan yeah read the left side as bars and not atmospheres (EDIT: I didn't. what am I even doing?). Will update.

Comment: As I read that graph, 2.9 bar isn't all that close to nitrogen narcosis -- but anyway, oxygen toxicity will kill you a lot faster than nitrogen narcosis -- and still takes a while.  Didn't they used to run hyperbaric oxygenation chambers above 3 bar?